# View binding in activity have some issues with inflate and root

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, layout-inflater, android-inflate, android-viewbinding

I have issues with view binding in android studio with inflate and root.
below of inflate and root is a redline.

I also write view binding modules in build.gradle.
This is my build.gradle codes.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wallpaper.view"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}
```

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
```

And this is my activity codes.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

I have a read line below inflate and root.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I realize some of the modules in my build.gradle was not updated, Then I updated modules and issue or red line below of inflate, and root was gone.
There are the codes I updated.

from this

```
android {
namespace 'com.wallpaper.view'
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wallpaper.view"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

To this

```
android {
namespace 'com.wallpaper.view'
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wallpaper.view"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

I just update the version of compileSdk and targetSdk.